# Can I identify at runtime if my PHP support namespaces?

Tags: php, namespaces

I need to publish a single-class project with namespace support, but I want to allow lower versions of PHP (before 5.3) to use it. It's possible?

Comment: Not possible, namespaces were introduced in php 5.3.0, there's no support for previous versions.

Comment: It's possible to check the PHP version at runtime (see [`version_compare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)), but the problem is that any class containing a namespace declaration simply won't compile on anything lower than 5.3. So you could make a separate "checker" script, but you'd then need to conditionally load a different version of the file depending on the result. Out of curiosity, why do you need to support a version that hasn't had security support since 2011?

Comment: PHP 5.2 is dead for more than [7 years now](http://php.net/eol.php) and even PHP 5.6 will reach its [end of life](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) at the end of this year. Make your library work with PHP 5.6 or 5.5 and newer versions. Providing backward compatibility for any older PHP version is not worth the effort.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about those users, personally. http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: @iainn I work with a legacy application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As namespaces are supported by php version 5.3+ you could use some kind of version switch to decide which class definition should be loaded:

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
    // php 5.3+, load class with namespace
    require_once('my-namespaced-class.php');
} else {
    require_once('my-class.php');
}
```

This is surely a ugly wrapper but it should allow you to reach your goal.